# LINQ need to parse JSON out of a column

Tags: c#, json, linq

In a table, Leads, there is a column `Data` that contains a JSON string.  In a LINQ statement, I need to extract a field from that JSON:

```
var results = from l in leads
    select new MyLeadObject
    {
        LeadID = l.LeadID,
        ...
        RequestType = (string)l.Data["RequestTypeID"]
    };
```

Here's a shortened version of the JSON:

```
{  
   "RequestTypeID":1
}
```

`RequestTypeID` is a string.

I've been reading other threads and trying to cobble this together.  Not having much luck.

**EDIT:**

With help from Nkosi, I got this far:

```
RequestType = (string)JSONNetSerialization.DeserializeJsonNet<LeadData>(l.Data).RequestTypeID
```

The only problem is that LeadData.RequestTypeID is an enum, so it won't convert the enum to a string.  I'm not sure how to get the value of the enum instead of the entire enum itself. Outside of LINQ I could do this: `RequestTypeID.GetDisplayName();` but `.GetDisplayName()` is not recognized by LINQ.

Comment: You can use JSON.Net to parse the Data field to get the property. But the query would need to be realized first as linq to sql will kick up a fuss

Comment: I'm not sure I follow

Comment: is `leads` a direct call to the table or is it already in memory

Comment: It is in memory.  Previously, it was populated with a call to the DB to load all records from the Lead table

Comment: Ok that makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Json.Net` to parse the JSON in `Data` field to get the property.

```
var results = leads.Select(l =>
    new MyLeadObject {
        LeadID = l.LeadID,
        //...
        RequestType = (string)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(l.Data)["RequestTypeID"]
    });
```

Comment: I'm getting: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Comment: I have an actual object I could use instead of `dynamic`.  But it's complicated by the fact that RequestTypeID is an enum

Comment: getting close!  DeserializeObject still wants a type. I tried this, but this isn't it either: DeserializeJsonNet<string>(l.Data)["RequestTypeID"]

Comment: C#, NET 4.5, MVC, VS2015 -- hope one of those answers your question.  Sure do appreciate your help!

Comment: And you have latest version of Json.Net referenced?

Comment: You'll have to convert the `int` value back to an enum before trying to get the string representation of the enum. while RequestTypeID is an enum, it is stored as an `int` when serialized to Json.

Comment: That makes sense in theory :-)  In practice, and inside a LINQ statement, I don't know how to do that.  Should I start a new question? You answered my original question.

Comment: Yes you could start a new question if your original issue was resolved. I'm looking into the converting it back to enum.

Comment: Apparently I need to wait 90 minutes to post a new question.

Comment: Ok then. what is the enum type

Comment: I'm thinking I will add the enum as a property to the object I'm trying to create.  This will make things easier, although it will require some adjusting downstream.  Thanks for your help!